# Sending nested JSON Objects to datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

My JSON data looks like this and I am trying to get it sent through datatables.

```
{
    "RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-1":
    {
        "column1": "stuff",
        "column2": "more stuff",
        "column3": "example"
    },
    "RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-2":
    {
        "column1": "stuff",
        "column2": "more stuff",
        "column3": "example"
    },
    { ... }
}
```

I can't figure out how to look passed `RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-1`, etc and go straight for the data. This is what I have so far. Anyone think they could help?

```
var theTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaData": data, //data == my above JSON object
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "column1" },
        { "mData": "column2" },
        { "mData": "column3" }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function that "normalizes" the JSON. Like this :

```
function normalize(data) {
    var result = [];
    for (var row in data) {
        result.push(data[row]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then call that function in your dataTables initialisation :

```
var theTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
    aaData: normalize(data),
    aoColumns: [
        { mData: "column1" },
        { mData: "column2" },
        { mData: "column3" }
    ]    
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o27hgzjr/**

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to need `RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-1` too. But thanks for the idea. Will this be time consuming if I have 1000+ pieces of data?

Comment: hey @bryan If you are worried about time consuming, using 1.000 records, you shouldnt use jQuery dataTables at all :) Made a little test : A JSON with 1000 unique rows, `normalize()` takes about 0.850ms using `console.time()` - rendering / initializing the dataTable takes about 1.000 times as long. What do you need `RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-1` for? You didnt mention that in your question. Remember, `RANDOM-UNIQUE-STRING-1` etc is **not** deleted, you still have them in `data`, you are just getting rid of them according to insert the rows in the dataTables correctly.

Comment: @davidkronrad I wanted to use it because it would be a part of a `href` in my datatable. dataTables has worked really well for me, do you have any other suggestions on what you would use? I can't find anything better.